# The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0 | 3.1 | 5.0 | 6.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, msbuild

I've just downloaded the release version of .NET Core 3.0.100
It was installed alongside older version that I have:

[image]

When I try to run `dotnet restore` for a project that targets .NET Core 3 (`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>`), I get this error

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0.  Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.0.
```

I have a global.json file that explicitly states that I need the `3.0.100` SDK

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.0.100"
  }
}
```

I know that I can edit the `MSBuildSDKsPath` env variable to point to the `3.0.100` SDK, and it works, but I don't want to do it, I have other projects on my machine that still need to use older versions of .NET Core.

Is there a way to make the `dotnet` tool use the SDK that's stated in `global.json` instead of the one in `MSBuildSDKsPath`?

Edit: I use Visual Studio Code

Comment: The great thing about having a standard .NET library, is that there are [so many standards to choose from.](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but when I got this error, deleting all my bin, obj, internal build outputs, and .vs folders and then rebuilding made the error go away.  (Build clean was failing.)  I first got the error after trying to add new items to my project and it didn't go away when I removed them.

Answer (score 86):

You also have to update your `visual studio` to the minimum supported version:

### .NET Core 3.0

- minimum `visual studio v16.3`

### .NET Core 3.1

- minimum `visual studio v16.5`

### .NET Core 5.0

- minimum `visual studio v16.6 latest preview`

### .NET Core 6.0

- minimum `visual studio v17.0 latest preview`

---

[image]

(https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0)

---

[image: ![enter image description here]

(https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1)

---

[image]

(https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0)

---

[image]

(https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0)

Comment: Did you solve it? Maybe there is also an update for `vscode` needed

Comment: I had VS version 16.2.5, installed 16.3.7, and it fixed the issue!

Comment: I was having this problem with VS CODE. I updated VISUAL STUDIO to v16.3 and now VS Code is working properly. If you read through the error listing in VS Code, it references Visual Studio. That was my clue. Updated Visual Studio and all is good.

Comment: This answer is also relevant to users of Azure DevOps as a CI platform. The build agent (hosted or on-prem) needs to have access to the appropriate install of VS 2019 and using the appropriate dotnet tools version to build 3.0/3.1 projects.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Had the problem in a azure devops pipeline, and changing my build agent from a vs17 to 19 solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Danie I am faced with the same issue, where in the pipeline configuration can one change the build agent?

Comment: @RonnyMahlangu First make sure you have a 2019 build agent in you agent pool, and then in the pipeline settings you choose that in the setting called "Agent Specification".

Comment: Argh. As a follow-on, if you use one version of Visual Studio on a project and then accidentally open the same project in an older version of VS b/c, idk, the icon looks like the same color and shape, this happens as described. ◔_◔

Comment: When you are installing preview versions of .NET, ensure that 'Use previews of .NET Core SDK' is checked (Tools -> Options -> Preview Features)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in Azure DevOps with .NET 6:

> error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET
> 6.0.  Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0.

[image]

Solved by including the SDK like this:

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET 6 SDK'
  inputs:
    version: 6.0.x
    performMultiLevelLookup: true
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive#build-environment

Github thread about the issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6907

Answer (score 0):

Issues will be resolved going through below are the checklist

1. Environment Variable (Set it to Root folder) for ex. C:/Program Files/DotNet as PATH variable - Reboot to get changes affected
2. Check Visual Studio Version
3. Run dotnet --info to check SDKs are already installed
4. Delete MSBuildSDKPath if it is set in Environment Variables

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to build a solution using JetBrains Rider.  The problem turned out to be Rider using wrong msbuild.exe.  It was auto-detecting 2017 version instead of 2019.  I had to manually adjust it in JetBrains settings in `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolset and Build`.  See more details [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-30818/Creating-a-net-Core-app-with-30-ends-in-SDK-Error).